# Combining two <a> href links

Tags: html

I'm using Revolution Slider.
I'm adding a layer to the slide, and when I am inserting a button in the layer I use the following code:

```
<a href='#' class='tp-button blue small'>Blue Button</a>
```

I want the button to redirect to

```
<a href='http://www.hotelscombined.com/Place/Sydney.htm?a_aid=107946&brandid=289436' target='_blank' rel='nofollow'>Hotels in Sydney</a>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
<a class='tp-button blue small' href='http://www.hotelscombined.com/Place/Sydney.htm?a_aid=107946&brandid=289436' target='_blank' rel='nofollow'>Hotels in Sydney</a>
```

Adding additional properties to `<a>` tag won't hurt I guess.